# Node taking too long to respond

Tags: node.js

I wrote a very simple program to demonstrate request handling in Node (actually following a tutorial), but the server seems to take forever to respond to the `GET /` request. Here's the code I'm using:

```
const http = require('http');
const url = require('url');

let routes = {
    'GET': {
        '/': (req, res) => {
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-type': 'text/html'});
            res.end('GET /');
        }
    },
    'POST': {

    },
    'NA': (req, res) => {
        res.writeHead(404);
        res.end('Content not found');
    }
}

function router(req, res) {
    let baseURI = url.parse(req.url, true);
    // the function that gets resolved and used to handle the request
    let resolveRoute = routes[req.method][baseURI.pathname];
}

http
    .createServer(router).listen(3001, () => {
        console.log('Listening on port 3001');
    });
```

Something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Found it myself.

I was resolving the handler function but not calling it. Adding `resolveRoute(req, res);` to the end of the `router()` function makes it work. :)